# Range hood fan motor electrical breakdown noise

Tags: electrical, electric-motor, range, motor, range-hood

The sound is similar to a "buzz" of a high voltage line or a transformer hum. The volume varies with the fan speed rheostat setting and not the actual motor rpm. (Well, more like the difference between the setting and the actual rpm)

Other than being annoyingly loud, is there any electrical danger here? Is it due to improper instalment or lack of adequate insulation?

I'm renting the apartment, so if it is a hazard, then it is the landlord's responsibility to repair it. Otherwise, how would I go about repairing it?

Comment: Your description of the sound make me believe there is something loose in the hood or the mounting of the fan.

Comment: @rmdman: Agreed, this could be resonance rather than electrical, and that's what I'd check first.

Comment: with motor off can you move the fan freely

Comment: @Ruskies Yes, the fan spins freely. What is the best way to post a video on this site?

Comment: @RMDman the thing is, the volume of the noise is instantly louder as soon as the rheostat setting changes to a higher setting, before the fan has a chance to speed up

Answer (score 1):

A partially stalled fan motor can make buzzing sounds. Stalling could be caused by friction due to lack of lubrication or buildup of greasy deposits, or mechanical rubbing on nearby parts. Stalled fan motors can get very, very hot. Some house fires have been caused by such overheated ventilation fans. I've personally encountered several little bathroom fans that had been cooked blue, and the surroundings badly scorched. Many range hood fans can be easily accessed after removing the mesh filter element.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's stalled, since I can spin it freely and it doesn't rub on anything when I do.